# Layout some grid columns vertically on small screens

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

I have a form that looks like this:

[image: wireframe]

I have laid it out using CSS grid:

```html
<div style="display: inline-grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto">
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px;">⊖</div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px;">⊖</div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px;">⊖</div>
</div>
```

On small screens I would like the layout to change to this:

[image: wireframe]

But I don't know how to change the CSS grid to get this layout, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make those `<div>`s with `<input>` span 3 columns, those without span 3 rows and ensure that the grid is as dense as possible:

```css
#container {
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #container > :not(:nth-child(4n)) {
    grid-column: 1 / -2;
  }
  #container > :nth-child(4n) {
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: span 3;
  }
}
```

Try it:

```css
#container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

#container > :nth-child(4n) {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #container > :not(:nth-child(4n)) {
    grid-column: 1 / -2;
  }
  #container > :nth-child(4n) {
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: span 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div>⊖</div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div>⊖</div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div>⊖</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some `:nth-child()` logic that may be helpful.

(re-size the screen to switch between layouts)

```css
@media ( max-width: 1500px ) {
    .container > div:nth-child(4)   { grid-row: 1; }
    .container > div:nth-child(8)   { grid-row: 4; }
    .container > div:nth-child(12)  { grid-row: 7; }
    .container > div                { grid-column: 1 }
    .container > div:nth-child(4n)  { grid-column: 2 };
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="display: inline-grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto">
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px;">⊖</div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px;">⊖</div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div><input></div>
  <div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px;">⊖</div>
</div>
```